# Css3 анимация использовать scale и translate однавременно

Tags: css3, анимация, transform

Я хочу делать анимацию пара, но что-то не сходится: проблема с translate и scale-ом, как-то они не работают вместе однвременно.

HTML:

```
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uU_C0PBe64k/VSd6800h1bI/AAAAAAAAFM8/hp-vH8wT3U4/w63-h57-no/steam.png" />
```

SCSS:

```
@mixin steamLeft($speed, $delay) {
    -webkit-animation-name: steamLeft;
    animation-name: steamLeft;
    animation-duration: $speed;
    animation-delay: $delay;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 63px;
    height: 57px;
    @include steamLeft(2s,0);
}

@keyframes steamLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0) scale(0);
    }

    10% {
        transform: translateX(10px) scale(0.5);
    }

    20% {
        transform: translateX(20px) scale(1);
    }
}
```

[Код на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/npvdtaLu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, тебе нужно что-то вроде [этого](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPegvx)?

Можно просто сместить `transform-origin`.

Comment: ооо как я забыл про это спасибо большое вы мне спасли просто